# How do I get kate to restore last used session?

Tags: kubuntu, session, kate

I have two computers and both have exactly the same behavior. I have the option "load last used session" selected, but every time, Kate starts a new session. What could be causing this?

Here are the permissions of `~/.kde/share/apps`

```
mike@mike-laptop:~/.kde/share/apps$ ls -l
<..>
drwx------ 4 mike mike 4096 2011-08-19 10:58 kate
<..>

mike@mike-laptop:~/.kde/share/apps$ ls -l kate
-rw------- 1 mike mike 2927 2011-08-19 10:58 metainfos
drwx------ 5 mike mike 4096 2011-03-18 09:49 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 2 mike mike 4096 2011-03-18 09:49 sessions
```

Also starting kate from the command line produces no output at all.

Comment: If it makes a difference, both computers also have Gnome installed.

Comment: ~10 years later, this is still a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433237).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Yep. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=268913

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open `~/.kde/share/config/katerc` and verify if these are in there:

```
[General] 
Last Session=mysession.katesession 
Restore Window Configuration=true 
Session Exit=save
```

There has been a long outstanding bug where sometimes some of the settings are not properly saved.

Comment: This was exactly it. Except that `Session Exit` wasn't there at all and it worked without it too. Now, any idea why this would happen on two separate computers? Would installing kubuntu-desktop on top of ubuntu-desktop have anything to do with it?

Comment: it should not. kubuntu and ubuntu -should- be seperate systems not touching each other. But I saw the katerc mentioned in a bug as sometimes not saving settings and quickly also found these 3 settings related to sessions. It was more of a guess than anything else ;) Glad it workd out!

Comment: Well I'm glad it worked. It just seems strange to me that it has this behavior on two separate computers, one of which is a fresh install of 11.04.

Comment: For some reason the setting `Last Session` got reverted on both computers to being empty a day or two later. I had to set it again.

Comment: Same here, Last Session gets erased when kate is not running and I open a file with Dolphin. I am afraid this is not considered a bug... See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdesdk/+bug/774985

Comment: As of KDE 5.21 (Feb 2021), `katerc` is in `~/.config`, and the `Last Session` and `Session Exit` keys no longer exist. The [session restore bug is still there](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433237)

Comment: @DanDascalescu for me putting the variables into ~/.config/katerc did actually work!